# Sampling theorem condition

Tags: signal-processing

I have this signal $$ x(t) = \sin(2 \pi f_0 t ) $$ with $ T_c= \frac{1}{2f_0} $ but I don't know if the Nyquist condition Is verified. The condition should be $ f_c \geq B_x $ where $ B_x $ is the bilateral band. I know that $ f_c= \frac{1}{T_c} = 2f_0 $ but I don’t know how to find $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x(t) = \sin(2 \pi f_0 t )$ then $X(j\omega) = \frac{\pi}{j}[\delta(\omega - 2 \pi f_0) - \delta(\omega + 2 \pi f_0)]$. So for satisfying sampling theorem condition we should have $$\omega_s \gt 2\times2\pi f_0$$
Where $\omega_s = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ is sampling frequency. Note that it should be $\gt$ instead of $\ge$ . See [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44936/sampling-a-sinusoidal-signal-at-the-nyquist-rate) for the reason.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: @S.H.W why did you take $X(j \omega)$ instead of $X(\omega)$?

Comment: @Migalobe It's just a convention in EE.

Comment: ok, but the result is the same right?

Comment: @Migalobe Yes, different names for the same function.

Comment: @S.H.W they are different. btw, if I understood well, you took $2\pi f_0 >0$ bcuz it makes what is inside the first delta function vanish. Is that correct?